# Expected token 'eof' found '@'

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm learning xslt and xpath .While selecting an attribute from a node I'm getting this error
**Expected token 'eof' found '@'.**

here are my XML and XSL files:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>
<inventory>
<drink>
    <lemonade supplier="mother" id="1">
        <price>$2.50</price>
        <amount>20</amount>
    </lemonade>
    <pop supplier="store" id="2">
        <price>$1.50</price>
        <amount>10</amount>
    </pop>
</drink>
<snack>
    <chips supplier="store" id="3">
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <amount>60</amount>
        <calories>180</calories>
    </chips>
</snack>
</inventory>
```

XSL FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/" >
<html>
<body>
<xsl:value-of select="inventory/snack/chips@supplier"/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is that really the actual error message? The error message itself seems ill-formed (English).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a slash:

```
<xsl:value-of select="inventory/snack/chips/@supplier"/>
```